# jquery do something after element clicked every 5 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use jQuery to do something `.addClass` everytime a button is clicked -- every 5 times. So, every 5 clicks class '`.remove`' gets added - after the 5th click each time this class is removed.

Comment: Declare a counter in the outer scope of the event handler function, and update the counter in handler.

Comment: 1) Use .data() or .attr() methods to store a counter 2) Increment counter on every click 3) If `counter % 5 === 0`, swap classes

Comment: Yay! Stackoverflow is so awesome!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a really simple solution which is also scalable:

```js
$(function() {

  $('button').click(function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var counter = ((btn.data('click-counter') || 0) + 1) % 5;

    btn.text('Click me (' + counter + ')');
    btn.data('click-counter', counter);
    btn.toggleClass('remove', !counter);
  });

});
```

```css
button.remove {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<button>Click me</button>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var clickCount = 0;

$("#clickme").click(function () {
    clickCount++;

    if (clickCount % 5 === 0)
        // do your removeClass here
    else
        // do your addClass here

    $(this).text("click count " + clickCount);
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prcgopnd/2/

All I do here is store a counter variable, and every time the button is clicked, I increment this counter.  To test for "every 5th click", just modulus by 5 and test for a zero value (in other words the click count is divisible by 5 with no returning leftover value).